# Referencing external css file with XMLWorker

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I have switched from ***HtmlWorker*** to ***XMLWorker*** in order to take advantage of the use of *external css files*. Besides, in this way, I avoid the use of inline styling.

This is currently my code:

```
public ActionResult ViewPdf(object model)
    {
        var doc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 10f, 1f, 10f, 30f);

        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;

        doc.Open();

        var xmltext = RenderActionResultToString(View(model));

        var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
        cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StyleSheet1.css"), true);

        var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
                                               new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

        var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        var parser = new XMLParser(worker);

        using (var sr = new StringReader(xmltext))
        {

            parser.Parse(sr);
        }


        doc.Close();

        var buf = new byte[memStream.Position];
        memStream.Position = 0;
        memStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        return new BinaryContentResult(buf, "application/pdf");
    }
```

**RenderActionResultToString(View(model))** is giving me the string I want to parse into pdf. This all works fine. The problem is with the styles. If I use inline styling such as:

```
<table style ="width: 400px">
```

, everything works like a charm. But if I use something like:

```
<table class = "foo">
```

, and reference a css file(StyleSheet1.css) like this:

```
.foo {
    width: 400px;
}
```

, it doesn't work...

I tried referencing the stylesheet in the string I am parsing, like this in my view:

```
    <head>
        <link href ="@Server.MapPath("~/Content/StyleSheet1.css")" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
    </head>
```

I inserted the link to the css file just as the [documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html) states, inside the head tags.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A relative path maybe? As in <link href ="Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: try "**wwwroot/**your/stylesheet/path"